.NET Core 6 AES CFB with Zeros as Padding Decryption Output is Wrong
I am writing a console app using .NET 6.0.421 to test around AES-128 CFB mode with BlockSize of 128 and the same bit count for FeedbackSize.
I have the following code for the decryption. The encryption is very similar bar for aes.CreateEncryptor(), IV, and Key generation.
private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] iv, byte[] key)
{
    var aes = Aes.Create()!;
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
    aes.BlockSize = 128;
    aes.FeedbackSize = 128;
    aes.Key = key;
    aes.IV = iv;

    using var stream = new MemoryStream();
    using var cryptos = new CryptoStream(stream, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write, true);
    cryptos.Write(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);
    cryptos.Close();

    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return stream.ToArray();
}

Both of the encrypt and decrypt are used in this way:
byte[] key;
byte[] iv;

string input = "1171713971804";
byte[] plain = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
Console.WriteLine("Data\t\t\t: "+ input);
byte[] encrypted = encrypt(plain, out iv, out key);
byte[] decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, iv, key);
Console.WriteLine("Data Dec Length : " + decrypted.Length);
Console.WriteLine("Data Dec\t\t: "+ Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted));

You can find the full source on .Net Fiddle but keep in mind that it seems invalid characters are weeded out from the output. The decryption result with PaddingMode.ANSIX923 looks perfect while on PaddingMode.Zeros have three question marks (possibly invalid characters) despite both decryption outputs 16 bytes of data.
Output with PaddingMode.Zeros:
Data            : 1171713971804
Data Dec Length : 16
Data Dec        : 1171713971804???

Output with PaddingMode.ANSIX923:
Data            : 1171713971804
Data Dec Length : 16
Data Dec        : 1171713971804

I do curious, what might be the cause for the difference of decryption output for PaddingMode.ANSIX923 and PaddingMode.Zeros?

With zero-padding, the padding bytes are not removed during decryption, as you can easily verify with a hex encoding of the decrypted data, s. https://dotnetfiddle.net/zXwcWf

@Topaco ah no wonder. thank you for the insight.

With ANSI X9.23 padding (and also with the most commonly used padding PKCS#7), the information about the number of padding bytes is contained in the padding so that the padding can be reliably removed after decryption. This is not the case with Zero padding. There, padding is performed with 0x00 values and if the original plaintext ends with one or more 0x00 values, it is not possible to differentiate between 0x00 data bytes and 0x00 padding bytes, meaning that the padding cannot be reliably removed. See also Padding.
